# Disable default Sonata success message

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm working with Sonata Admin Bundle and I'm trying to remove or rewrite default message for success: "Item X has been successfully created."

How can I do that ? Is there any possibility to set new message as parameter and rewrite the default message ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `SonataAdminBundle.en.yml` in `app/Resources/translations` and add the following translation:

```
flash_create_success: Item "%name%" created!!!!
```

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#translations